# Windows Phone 7JSON HTTPWebrequest Synchronous

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, synchronous

We have a thread where it needs to be synchronous in Windows Phone 7. We need to send HTTPWebrequest one by one until the thread is completed, so that the next thread can start . As WP7 is asynchronous , we need a solution which is made synchronous. the output is in the form of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (and shouldn't!!!) make this synchronous.
instead use a queuing mechanism, or code with the new async/await task pattern, which allow you to more or less write code as if it was synchronous

Comment: I tried with ASYNC/Await. Before the Response gets called , it becomes asynchronous. Here is the code for your reference.

Comment: webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);

Comment: Right. It's still async, but your code looks synchronous and it just makes it easier to write async code and do this kinda stringed together type of code. As I said earlier you can't really make this synchronous (well there is kinda a way using thread locking but it's extremely error prone and very likely to create deadlocks). You really should design for stuff being async (not to mention you could fail certification if your web requests takes too long since the app would be unresponsive for a long time)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with ASYNC/Await. Before the Response gets called , it becomes asynchronous. Here is the code for your reference.

```
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            // creating JSON object
            JObject json =
            new JObject(new JProperty(VMConstants.JSON_CONSTANT_LOGINCMD, new JObject(
            new JProperty("employeeId", constant.EMPLID)
            )));
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(postStream))
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                json.WriteTo(writer, null);
            }
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);

                    // Start the web reponse
            postStream.Close();
```